# Authentication to a private GCP Registry on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

We have a Jenkins as a CI/CD tool and recently my company moved to workers hosted on Kubernetes. I'm trying to understand how it works.

This is an example pipeline that uses public image hosted on dockerhub

```
podTemplate(containers: [
    containerTemplate(
        name: 'aws', 
        image: 'amazon/aws-cli:latest',
        command: 'sleep',
        args: '99d',
        envVars: [
          envVar(key: "AWS_REGION", value: "eu-central-1"),
          envVar(key: "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", value: "eu-central-1")
        ])
  ]) 

  {
    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('Testing the acccess') {
            container('aws') {
                withCredentials([aws(accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'anthos-aws-creds', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')]) {
                  stage('Shell Execution') {
                      sh 'aws help'
                      sh 'aws autoscaling help'
                      sh 'aws eks list-clusters'
                      sh 'aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"'
                  }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and it works just fine.

But now I want to use an image from a **private** registry on GCP and I just don't know how to. Here's my code:

```
podTemplate(containers: [
    containerTemplate(
        name: 'gcp', 
        image: 'gcr.io/my_project_id/my_image:latest',
        command: 'sleep',
        args: '99d',
  ]) 

  {
    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('Testing the acccess to GCP') {
            container('gcp') {
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'gcp-sa-key', variable: 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')]) {
                  stage('Shell Execution') {
                      sh 'gcloud auth activate-service-account $SVC_ACCOUNT_EMAIL --key-file $SVC_ACCOUNT_FILE'
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error that such repository doesn't exists. I checked the name and I'm 100% sure that the name is correct.

Comment: If you instead run a command such as list repos, do you get the proper output? If not, then it is obviously an authentication issue and that error is misleading.

Comment: @MB I cant run any command. The pipeline fails when it wants to download the image for the pod which is the first step of the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with private registries, you must make sure you set up “ImagePullSecret” as this will contain the service account credentials that have permissions to access your GCR. Also ensure that the “Storage Object Viewer” role for the service account is added. You might want to check firewall configuration as it may be a factor with the access issues.

Attached is a documentation for supplementary reference.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#creating-a-secret-with-a-docker-config